# Draw circle and rectangle in canvas using Fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to draw three shapes. Using three separate functions.

1. line
2. circle
3. Rectangle

Three functions are works fine. But if i want to draw a line and circle both(run two functions one after other). First one work fine but second one it will draw the first one and second both in same coordination.And it will repeat.Is there a way to draw a one shape at one time.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1', {
  selection: false
});

var line, isDown;


function myFun() {
  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    var points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
    line = new fabric.Line(points, {
      strokeWidth: 20,
      fill: '#07ff11a3',
      stroke: '#07ff11a3',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });
    canvas.add(line);
  });
}
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  line.set({
    x2: pointer.x,
    y2: pointer.y
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
  isDown = false;
});

function drawcle() {

  var circle, isDown, origX, origY;

  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    circle = new fabric.Circle({
      left: pointer.x,
      top: pointer.y,
      radius: 1,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      stroke: 'red',
      fill: 'White',
      selectable: false,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });
    canvas.add(circle);
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    circle.set({
      radius: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
    isDown = false;
  });

}

function drawrec() {
  var line, isDown, origX, origY;

  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    line = new fabric.Rect({
      left: origX,
      top: origY,
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      width: pointer.x - origX,
      height: pointer.y - origY,
      angle: 0,
      fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
      transparentCorners: false
    });
    canvas.add(line);
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

    if (origX > pointer.x) {
      line.set({
        left: Math.abs(pointer.x)
      });
    }
    if (origY > pointer.y) {
      line.set({
        top: Math.abs(pointer.y)
      });
    }

    line.set({
      width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)
    });
    line.set({
      height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y)
    });


    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
    isDown = false;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<div class="stamps">
  <div class="set1">

    <a class="thmb" href="#" onclick="myFun()">Line</a></br>
    <a class="thmb" href="#" onclick="drawcle()">Draw Circle</a></br>
    <a class="thmb" href="#" onclick="drawrec()">Draw Rectangle</a>


  </div>


  <div class="area">
    <div class="col" id="droppable">
      <canvas id="canvas1" width="720" height="560" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a way to draw on canvas with out holding click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeEvents(){
 canvas.off('mouse:down');
 canvas.off('mouse:up');
 canvas.off('mouse:move');
}
```

You can use `canvas.off()` to remove the event listener from canvas. It was drawing other shapes because its adding the listeners to canvas, so when you call the drawing function remove the attached listeners from canvas then add your current listener.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1', {
  selection: false
});

var line, isDown;


function drawLine() {
  removeEvents();
  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    var points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
    line = new fabric.Line(points, {
      strokeWidth: 20,
      fill: '#07ff11a3',
      stroke: '#07ff11a3',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });
    canvas.add(line);
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    line.set({
      x2: pointer.x,
      y2: pointer.y
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
    isDown = false;
  });
}

function drawcle() {

  var circle, isDown, origX, origY;
  removeEvents();
  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    circle = new fabric.Circle({
      left: pointer.x,
      top: pointer.y,
      radius: 1,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      stroke: 'red',
      fill: 'White',
      selectable: false,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });
    canvas.add(circle);
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    circle.set({
      radius: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
    isDown = false;
  });

}

function drawrec() {
  var rect, isDown, origX, origY;
  removeEvents();
  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: origX,
      top: origY,
      originX: 'left',
      originY: 'top',
      width: pointer.x - origX,
      height: pointer.y - origY,
      angle: 0,
      fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
      transparentCorners: false
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

    if (origX > pointer.x) {
      rect.set({
        left: Math.abs(pointer.x)
      });
    }
    if (origY > pointer.y) {
      rect.set({
        top: Math.abs(pointer.y)
      });
    }

    rect.set({
      width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)
    });
    rect.set({
      height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y)
    });


    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
    isDown = false;
  });
}

function removeEvents(){
 canvas.off('mouse:down');
 canvas.off('mouse:up');
 canvas.off('mouse:move');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<div class="stamps">
  <div class="set1">

    <a class="thmb" href="#" onclick="drawLine()">Line</a></br>
    <a class="thmb" href="#" onclick="drawcle()">Draw Circle</a></br>
    <a class="thmb" href="#" onclick="drawrec()">Draw Rectangle</a>


  </div>


  <div class="area">
    <div class="col" id="droppable">
      <canvas id="canvas1" width="720" height="560" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a way to draw on canvas with out holding click ?

Comment: @Caster, you want to draw line?